# Is there a way to declare a Func in C# with a generic type?

Tags: c#, func

Would like some code a bit like this:
`Func<T>< List<T>,T > myFunc = (inputList) => inputList.First();`

I can define a Func without generic type but not sure how to do it generically, i.e add the 'T's.Is it possible?

Comment: You can declare such Func inside a class or function which is already generic. `public class MyClass<T>{ Func<List<T>, T> myFunc = (inputList) => inputList.First(); }`

Comment: Thanks Chetan, good idea, ive updated the question slightly to try to make it clearer that isnt what im after in this case.

Comment: If you know the element type of the list, you can specify it directly: `Func<List<string>, string> myFunc = (inputList) => inputList.First();`

Comment: No idea what you want to achieve... Can you please [edit] post to clarify? Also what is exact errors you are facing? Normally it is not a problem to define generic types, presumably you are doing it inside a generic method/class already... You may also want to clarify bigger goal.

Comment: I've been unable to solve, but in my case a local method works just as well

```T genericLocalMethod<T>(List<T> paramList)
                {
                    return paramList.First();
                }```